# How to prove equivalence relation in this case?

Tags: proof-techniques, lambda-calculus

I am working on $\lambda$-terms and trying to prove the $=$ is an equivalence relation on $\lambda$-terms. My problem is proving reflexive relation.

$\frac{}{\theta \vdash x = x}$

$\frac{ \theta,x \# N, y \# M \vdash  M  = [y := x]N }
          { \theta \vdash  \texttt{$\lambda x.M$ $=$ $\lambda y.N$}   } $

$\frac{\theta \vdash  M_1 = M_2 \quad N_1 = N_2  }
          { \theta \vdash  \texttt{$M_1 \, N_1$ $=$ $M_2 \,N_2$} }$

I put two restrictions on such $\lambda$-terms.First, bound variables are distinct. 
For example, there are no two terms such as $\lambda x.M$ and $\lambda x.N$.
Second, multiple bindings of a variable is not allowed. 
For example, $\lambda x. \lambda x.M$ should be written as $\lambda y. \lambda x.M$.
To sum up, every bound variable should be distinct. 
$[y := x]N$ means variable $x$ replaces variable $y$ in term $N$.
$x \# N$ means $x$ does not occur in $N$.
$\theta$ is a set of $\#$.
Also, $\alpha$-equivalence is assumed for the terms.
For example, $\lambda x.x = \lambda y.y$

I tried to prove that the $=$ shown in above rules is an equivalence relation on such terms.

For equivalence relation, I have to prove the following three relations.

reflexive: $\theta \vdash M=M$.

symmetric : $\theta \vdash M=N$ implies $\theta \vdash N=M$.

transitive: $\theta \vdash M=N$ and $\theta \vdash N=P$ implies $\theta \vdash M=P$.

The proof of reflexive relation is the following.

when $M$ is a variable such as $x$, then $x = x$.

when $M$ is an application such as $M_1 \,N_1$), then I have 
$M_1 \,N_1$ = $M_1 \,N_1$, so it is true.

when $M$ is an abstraction such as $\lambda x.M$, from $\lambda x.M = \lambda x.M$, I have $ x \# M \vdash | M=[x:=x]M $, which is not true becuase $x \in M$.
Also, as I said, there are no two terms such as $\lambda x.M$ and $\lambda x.M$, so I cannot show $M=M$ for an abstraction.

Since $\alpha$-equivalence is assumed for terms. I assume that $M=\lambda x.M_1 =\lambda y.M_2$. Therefore, I will have $x \# M_2, y \# M_2 \vdash  M_1=[y:=x]M_2$? is this the right way to prove  reflexivity?

I would appreciate your kind help.

Comment: It seems impossible to me to prove $\lambda x.x = \lambda x.x$ with those restrictions. Can you actually prove that?

Comment: @chi I think I can't write $\lambda x.x = \lambda y.y$ because of the restriction. Any idea?

Comment: I'm quite unsure about this. It seems that reflexivity fails on $\lambda x.x$. If so, the system can not be reflexive, unless the restrictions are relaxed or the definition is adapted somehow.

Comment: @chi how about write $\lambda y.y = 　\lambda x.x$ since both are the same lambda term. Since $\lambda x.x$   represents a class of terms. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Yes that should be provable, one starts from $x=x$ which is the same as $x=[y:=x]y$. Then, since $x\# y$ and $y\# x$ one can have $\lambda x.x = \lambda y.y$. If you consider $\alpha$-convertible terms as equal, then the relations above might be reflexive, after all (I'm unsure at the moment).

Comment: @chi just to make sure. To prove reflexive relation, in the case of $P$ is being an abstraction,  i write $\lambda x.M =\ lambda y.N$ and assume that $P  =\lambda x.M = \lambda y.N$ since they are in elements of a set represented by  an  absrraction.  This way, i can prove it. My question is that how  people think?  Do they think it is ok?  Or do they insist i must take syntactically same term,  in which reflexivity will fails.  How can i justify it in the first case?  How can i convince people?

Comment: @chi it would be great if you could write your ideas about our discussion as an answer. I think this topic will be a controversial one.

Comment: What relation do you mean by =? Lambda calculus has many notions of equality, many of which are reflexive by definition. The most well known ones are $=_{\beta}$ and $=_{\beta\eta}$.

Comment: @MartinBerger by $=$, I mean $\alpha$-equality, two terms are equal up to renaming of their bound variables.  I assume this for terms and try to prove the relation, shown as inference rues, is an equivalence relation.  Also, I restrict bound variables to be distinct, as I said in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will only prove reflexivity $A=A$. We proceed by induction on the structure of $A$.

If $A\equiv x$, then $x=x$ follows from rule 1.

If $A\equiv \lambda x. M$, then by induction hypothesis we can assume $M=M$ is provable. Now, take any $y$ not free in $M$. We have $M \equiv [y:=x][x:=y]M$ by construction. Let $N \equiv [x:=y]M$. Rule two states

$$
\dfrac{
  x\# N, y\# M \vdash M=[y:=x]N
}{
\vdash \lambda x.M = \lambda y.N
}
$$

We indeed have $x\# N$, since the $x$ variable was renamed as $y$ in $N \equiv [x:=y]N$. We also have $y\# M$ by our choice of $y$. Induction hypothesis states $M=M$, which is $M=[y:=x]N$. Hence, the conclusion of the rule holds, which is $\lambda x. M = \lambda y. [x:=y]M$. If terms are identified up-to $\alpha$, then this equality is the same as $\lambda x.M = \lambda x.M$.

If $A=MN$, the induction hypotheses and rule 3 suffice.

Comment: I usually follow my intuition, and I am not good at presenting them. With discussing with you above and after reading your proof, I clarified some points which were not clear to me. Thank you, helped me a lot.